# Assign multiple term sets to a single column

Tags: managed-metadata, column, library

Is it possible to assign multiple term sets to a single column in 2010?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No

If you want to reference multiple Term SETS then you need to use multiple fields.

It is worth noting though that you can create a Search Managed Property which contains multiple different fields, so you could use that if you wanted to provide easy aggregations / filters which combine multiple different fields.

Comment: thanks for that.  Bit of a shame really.  What about creating a new group and then reusing the terms

Comment: I suppose you could do .. but got to ask what the requirement is for this?

Comment: my brief is the users want to limit the number of columns.  They simply want one column that displays the managed terms, but they need to be able to pick from multiple term sets.  Not sure what to do really.  I guess i could create a new term set that reuses all the values of the other term sets that they need.

Comment: If they are doing that, do you really need multiple term sets?

Comment: No you are right we probably don't if it was just going to be used for this one library.  The reason I want to split the values into separate term sets is because they are ripe for resuability.  e.g one term set will contain materials, one term set will contain specifications.  They just want all these term sets combined into one column for use in our best practice hub. However these terms could be used in other hubs / libraries that have nothing to do with best practice

Comment: Well when you create a Taxonomy / Managed Metadata field you don't have to point at the whole term set. You can limit it to a specific branch. The only thing to keep in mind is a Term Set has a maximum of 30,000 terms so as long as you won't hit that, you could just use one term set?